# Why does the output in python id strange

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi guys I am relatively new in python

Here is a code snippet

```
d = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'berry', 'c': 'cherry'}
for key in d:
  print key + " " + d[key]
```

I get output as

```
a apple
c cherry
b berry
```

I am using python 2.7.

Q1) Why is the output not serialized?

Q2) Can we get serialized output ?

Comment: what do you mean by serialized?

Comment: If you want to preserve the order, you should use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: pre- Python 3.6 dictionaries were unordered, so if you want to maintain the order of fields you would need an `OrderedDict` from `collections` module

Comment: Serialized means in order sorry i come from javascript background

Comment: Also can you guys explain how does the dictionary printing work?  Because now i have 3 elemwnts but what if I had n elements how would it print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python 2 are, by default, always unordered. You must use `OrderedDict()` to create an ordered dictionary in order to get serialized output.